# Has anyone setup DKIM with the CakePHP Email Component?

Tags: email, cakephp, dns, spam, spf

Has anyone successfully setup "Domain Keys Identified Mail" in a CakePHP app with the built-in email component?

I'm trying to implement part two of Jeff Atwood's spam protection post:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

I'm not finding any good tutorials or sample code online for doing this. I'm not sure I'm approaching this from the right angle either. (Might it be that the mail server itself on the box should be signing all outbound emails, and not the app?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on to the right path with having the mail server itself sign the emails. That will certainly help keep things DRY, especially if you have more than one application using the same mail server.

I've looked into doing the same thing from Cake and after a lot of study I determined that it was a lot (*a **lot***) easier to let a third-party handle your emails. I'd recommend [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com/) or even Amazon's new [Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) which has a free tier (*2,000 free emails per day*) which may cover the entirety of your application.